# R convert numeric vector to comma sep string

Tags: r

Read a csv file to data table , extracted the first column, then convert the column to a comma sep string. But the comma sep string format is scientific.

```
EAN <- fread(filepath,header=T,sep=",",select = c(1))

              EAN
  1:  17047048023
  2:  14190007787
  3:  11115000595
  4: 715480703234
  5:  27417500858
  6:  14130302041
  7:  12800011130
  8:  11111048172
  9:  14116342231
 10:  14133103116
 11:  17245798099
```

`EANstr<- as.character(unique(EAN[,1]))`  #Convert the vector to comma sep string

Here the output is

```
8.42236079117024e-314, 7.01079536177647e-314, 5.49153994749451e-314, 3.53494435730255e-312, 1.35460452687607e-313
```

How to avoid the conversion and get the result as below

```
'17047048023,14190007787,11115000595,715480703234,27417500858'
```

Tried using `tostring` as well as `options(scipen = 999)`. But doesnt give the correct result.

Comment: Try `toString(unique(EAN[[1]]))`.  You are converting to character and not `paste`ing together

Comment: Tried tostring too. But same result

Comment: Wait...do you _really_ want to represent `7e-314` without exponential notation?

Comment: You meant the scientifix notation.  `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: Yes i wanted the result as a string of comma separated numbers. as given in the post

Comment: Maybe use `colClasses="character"` in `fread`.

Comment: Try `paste(unique(EAN$EAN),collapse=",")`. That column is an `integer64` and so you see that strange behaviour. Coerce to a double (but keep in mind that you might lose precision) to obtain what you want.

Comment: colClasses="character" works. I can replace the double quotes in the next . Below is the sample result `c(\"17047048023\", \"14190007787\", \"11115000595\", \"715480703234\", \"27417500858\")`

Comment: paste has conversion error `(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. Also i could do this `EAN <- EAN[,EAN:= as.character(EAN)]` and then use `tostring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer based on comments.

1. while reading set the `colClasses="character"`

   `EAN <- fread(upcListPath,header=T,sep=",",colClasses="character")
   EANstr <- toString(unique(EAN[,EANCol]))`

If index is used instead of name it would create a slightly different string which would need further formatting. So below code gives different output

```
 `EANstr <- toString(unique(EAN[,1]))`
```

2. Change column data type after reading.

`EANstr <- toString(unique(as.character(EAN[,EANCol])))`

3. paste function after using `colclasses`

   `EAN <- fread(upcListPath,header=T,sep=",",colClasses="character")
   EANstr <- paste(unique(EAN$EANCol),collapse=",")`